# Phone gap + Sencha touch + ajax = progress event not firing

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I am using Sencha to post file (encoded with base64)

```
  Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: TheBestOfPets.Config.getBaseUrl() + 'api/upload',
                method: 'POST',
                params: jsonFile,
                timeout: 120000,
                success: function (response) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("Success", "Congratulation!!! Your photo has been successfully uploaded");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    Ext.Msg.alert("ERROR", "UPSSS! Photo was not uploaded. Try again please.");
                },
                progress: progressIndicator
            })
```

as you can see i have  "progress: progressIndicator" its just to show post progress, but problem is when i use built application this event is not fired...
But if i run application on webbrowser it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after investigating issue is a bit simple, i am using Android 4.0 and tested not packed using Chrome. When phonegap compile and run app it is runned in native browser which is not supporting XMLHttpRequest2 yet.